# How to read a file while it consists of different encoding?

Tags: java

It is possible to write both **byte array** and **List array** in one file, such as h.txt, in Java. However, as you know they have different formats and encodings. One possible way to write both byte array and List array in one file is to use a DataOutputStream, which allows you to write primitive values and strings to an output stream:

```
`byte[] bytes = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
 strings.add("Hello");
 strings.add("World");
 strings.add("!");

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("h.txt");
 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
 dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
 dos.write(bytes);
 dos.writeInt(strings.size());
 for (String s : strings) {
    dos.writeUTF(s);
 }`
```

And, in order to read the data from the file you can use the following code:

```
`FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("h.txt");
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
 int byteLength = dis.readInt();
 byte[] bytes = new byte[byteLength];
 dis.readFully(bytes);
 int stringSize = dis.readInt();
 List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++) {
    String s = dis.readUTF();
    strings.add(s);
 }`
```

But reading the data here was based on the fact that I was completely aware of the h.txt content.
My Question is:
How am I supposed to read the content of a file while I don't know anything about its content (byte array and List Array together in one file)?

Comment: You cannot read a file without knowing its structure.

Comment: Whatever software wrote the data must provide you with the format.  All software works this way;  even web browsers are only able to function because [HTTP is a standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616).

Comment: The information technology industry has never established a standard way of communicating file system metadata such as character encoding. Software must fall back on guesswork and luck, [heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I supposed to read the content of a file while I don't know anything about its content (byte array and List Array together in one file)?

You aren't.

To process a file, you must know, or be able to detect (e.g. by a special set of bytes that indicates the file type), how the data in the file is structured.